# Issue with the "more/less info" profile button

Tags: bug, profile-page

When opening the complete profile panel with the `more info` button, the panel gets its full size.

When closing it with the `less info` button, it becomes a size that is different from the size displayed when I click back on the menu button (in the top bar).

When you click `more info`, `less info` and on the top bar `profile` button, you should see a little glitch.

Is that normal?

[image: First step]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a couple screenshots of what you're seeing?

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you for this suggestion, see my edit.

Comment: It could use some freehand red circles to highlight the affected area.

Comment: Can't see any difference.

Comment: Between the "summary" and the "location" labels, there is a vertical space which is not the same in the two cases. I admit this is small, but the difference is real. If this is not enough useful to be mentionned, please say so that I do not repeat that mistake again.

Comment: What OS/browser are you using? This seems to be working fine for me in Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: @AnnaLear Same as you. When you click "more info", "less info" and on the top bar profile button, you should see a little glitch.

Comment: @cubitouch Ahh, I see it. I missed the "click the avatar in the top bar" third step.

Comment: @AnnaLear My bad, I should have been more precise =')

Comment: Minor, but repro'ed in Chrome 32, IE 10, FF 15, FF 18 on Win 7.